# Async post function in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise

I am trying to query mssql database to get password for the user, that is sending post request and then just show it in console. But the promise I've made isn't working the way I wanted to and the password isn't loaded into the variable. Here's my code:

```
app.post('/test', function () {
    let user = 'User';
    let query = 'SELECT [Password] as password FROM [Table] where [User] = ' + SqlString.escape(user);

    let password = (async function () {
        try {
            let pool = await sql.connect(dbConfig);
            let result = await pool.request()
                .query(querys);
            console.dir(result.recordset[0].password) //Value here is OK
            return result.recordset[0].password
        } catch (err) {
            // ... error checks
        }
    })()
    console.log(password); //here I am getting "Promise { pending }"
});
```

The result I get is: Promise { pending }
'DatabasePassword'

Comment: `let password = await (async function() {...} ())` as you are creating a promise with the `async` you need to `await` for it

Comment: Seen as your using `async`, just mark `app.post` as an `async` method then you can use `await` from the start.. `app.post('/test', async function () {`  No need for the anonymous function.

Comment: This will only work if the web framework used supports async middleware handlers. Express does not support that yet i think. Koa does.

Comment: It works fine with `express`..  The Promise is ignored, and you just handle the errors inside,.. I'll post an example..

Comment: With Koa though, you could actually assign async callbacks as middlewares and not have to do explicit error catching like this and the generic error handling middleware will handle it for you since Koa natively supports async/await.

Comment: @Spetastium  Yes, it would be nice if you could just return a Promise in express,..  Not sure if it's on there todo list, be nice if it was.. :)  ps.  I think I've used KOA before,  I liked it as it has a lot of stuff I don't use taken out, I think express still has the templating built in, something I don't use.

Comment: For express it seems like it will be included in version 5: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2259#issuecomment-341604767

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example of using `async / await` with express.

Express doesn't handle the errors, but that's no big problem you can handle them yourself, you could even wrap into a generic error handler to make things easier.

Anyway here is your code modified to use `async/await` in express.

```js
app.post('/test', async function (req, res) {
  try {  
    const user = 'User';
    const query = 'SELECT [Password] as password FROM [Table] where [User] = ' + SqlString.escape(user);
    const pool = await sql.connect(dbConfig);
    const result = await pool.request()
      .query(querys);
    const password = result.recordset[0].password;
    console.log(password);
    res.end(password);
  } catch (e) {
    res.end(e.message || e.toString());
  }
});
```

Comment: Will express propagate errors thrown inside a promise?

Comment: Were handling the error, so nothing to propagate.  You could do more fancy things with the error handling if you wanted.  You could even do `async function (req, res, next)` and call `next(err)` to push to next handler..

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem while using the MongoDB database, just made the post request async by adding keyword **async** to the function:

```
app.post('/register', async function(req,res){
  const myData = {username: req.body.name}
  const doesUserExists = await UserModel.exists(myData)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions marked as `async` returns a promise. That is a wrapper around a future resolution (value or error). A function that returns a promise (which `async` functions does automatically) either has to be resolved as a promise by chaining `.then(..)` or by "unwrapping" it with `await`.

A function that somewhere in its code `awaits` an `async` function needs to be `async` itself. That means that whatever calls that function needs to await it or resolve it as a promise and so forth.